# Ruby: how to transcode a utf-8 string?

Tags: ruby, utf-8, encode, transcode

My Thai string is:
"หลับตาฝัน ถึงชื่อเธอ"

and I need to output the utf-8 encoding like this:
"\u0e08\u0e2d\u0e21\u0e40\u0e27\u0e17\u0e22\u0e4c\u0e21\u0e2b\u0e32"

At the moment, I installed the 'iconv' gem and am using

```
string = Iconv.conv('unicode', 'utf-8', string)
```

But it's not working.

```
invalid encoding ("unicode", "utf-8") (Iconv::InvalidEncoding)
```

Do I need to use Iconv or encode? (I'm on Ruby 2.3.1)

Answer (score 0):

You are best of with `.encode`, it's in the standard library.
Iconv is being deprecated since Ruby 1.9.3

But when I do

```
"หลับตาฝัน ถึงชื่อเธอ".encode("utf-8")
```

I get another result as the one you want.

EDIT: not tested in IRB but in a script like this

```
# coding: UTF-8
p "หลับตาฝัน ถึงชื่อเธอ".encode("utf-8") # "\u0E2B\u0E25\u0E31\u0E1A\u0E15\u0E32\u0E1D\u0E31\u0E19\u0E16\u0E36\u0E07\u0E0A\u0E37\u0E48\u0E2D\u0E40\u0E18\u0E2D"
```

Are you sure of your desired result ?

Comment: In irb (and in my code)
`"หลับตาฝัน ถึงชื่อเธอ".encode("utf-8")`

Just outputs 
`"หลับตาฝัน ถึงชื่อเธอ"`

Comment: Thanks @peter

Seems like irb is not even recognising unicode:

`"หลับตาฝัน ถึงชื่อเธอ".encoding
=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
"\u0E2B\u0E25\".encoding
=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>`

Comment: can't even display the thai chars in irb, must be something about the codepage (I'm on windows), test it in a script like I EDITed

Comment: No, it's not working in irb or in my script. I am actually outputting results to json too and it is still in Thai, not unicode.

Comment: and is your script itself saved in utf-8 ?

Answer (score 0):

```
"DÃ©veloppement".encode("iso-8859-1").force_encoding("utf-8")
#=> "Développement"
```

You have to force the encoding.